# StringTemplate with Irrational number

Tags: output-formatting

How to keep irrational number as their original form rather than approximation when using StringTemplate?

```
StringTemplate["`1`"][Sqrt[3]]
```

This will output approximation "1.73205" rather than $\sqrt{3}$. And outputs "Pi" rather than $\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the setting `(ToString[#, StandardForm]&)` for the option [`InsertionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InsertionFunction.html):

```
StringTemplate["`1` and `2`", 
  InsertionFunction -> (ToString[#, StandardForm]&)][Sqrt[3], Pi]
```

[image]